# Laravel Sail Database & User not created

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

I just set up a laravel project with laravel sail and for some reason during build process it doesn't create the given database and user. I am quite confused as to why because I feel like I've configured everything right.

When executing `./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate` I get following error which indicates that the user given in my .env either doesn't exist or has wrong credentials:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'Laravel'@'192.168.0.5' (using password: YES) 
(SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = shop and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Checking my Database as root user showed me that it indeed hasn't got the `Laravel` user configured:

```
mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| root             | %         |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

After further inspection I found out that not even the database was created:

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

This is my .env:

```
PP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:nzYXOsqDlSiRuBsaDVcrUiKfQhekjhhpJlq3VKSo0M8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://domain.test

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=shop
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=
DB_USERNAME=Laravel
DB_PASSWORD=123456
...
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            # - pgsql
            - redis
            # - selenium
    # selenium:
    #     image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
    #     volumes:
    #         - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
    #     networks:
    #         - sail
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
#    pgsql:
#        image: postgres:13
#        ports:
#            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
#        environment:
#            PGPASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
#            POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE}'
#            POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
#            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
#        volumes:
#            - 'sailpostgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
#        networks:
#            - sail
#        healthcheck:
#          test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${DB_DATABASE}", "-U", "${DB_USERNAME}"]
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
    # memcached:
    #     image: 'memcached:alpine'
    #     ports:
    #         - '11211:11211'
    #     networks:
    #         - sail
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
#    sailpostgresql:
#        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

Of course I could create the database and user myself but since Sail/Docker-Compose ship with these options I want to make them work out of the box when setting up my project with Sail. Does anyone have an idea why the database and user are not created?

Comment: not familiar with this syntax. ${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}
do you think it is ok?

Comment: @AbdurRahman I think this means that it'll try reading the value for FORWARD_DB_PORT from ENV and if this doesnt exist it'll default to 3306. I think it's a default feature of bash called parameter-substitution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Okay, it seems like I accidentally created a mysql volume by running sail without an .env file, which was persistent the whole time thus of course having no user and database configured.

I executed `./vendor/bin/sail down --rmi all -v` to remove all images and volumes and then just ran `./vendor/bin/sail up` and it created the images and volumes from scratch. Now everything worked out and I can migrate my data.

Comment: This was exactly my problem too! Thanks for sharing

Comment: So useful for me, not only in this case but also for the cases that I have already created image and I really don't want them.
Thank you

Comment: Does anybody know what would be the pw when u did not set one :thinking:

Comment: This was my problem too, thanks!

Comment: So I was able to get it to create the database but for whatever reason it's not creating any of the tables, specifically the migrations table.  W/o it I can't run any of the migrations through artisan...  I have no idea what's going on. :(

Comment: I needed to do this.
I also needed to run `./vendor/bin/sail build --no-cache` before sailing up again.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `root` role to access

1. stop Sail
2. set `DB_DATABASE=` empty
3. set `DB_USERNAME=root`
4. run sail `$sail up`
5. run MySQL `$sail mysql`
6. done. `create` `update` `delete` user or databases