# Mysql docker container keeps restarting

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

The Container keeps restarting.
I tried

- docker-compose down -v
- docker volume rm

> The container was working fine earlier.

#### Logs

```
2021-03-27 13:16:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.

2021-03-27 13:16:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2021-03-27 13:16:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.

2021-03-27 13:16:08+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: MYSQL_USER="root", MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD are for configuring a regular user and cannot be used for the root user

Remove MYSQL_USER="root" and use one of the following to control the root user password:

- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

- MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD

- MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

#### Docker-compose.yml

```
 mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - "3306"
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE # CAP_SYS_NICE
    volumes:
      - ./cache/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./conf-mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: try change `MYSQL_USER=root` to `MYSQL_ROOT_USER=root`

Comment: I already tried that it didn't work

Comment: Your error message is clearly points to `MYSQL_PASSWORD` and `MYSQL_USER` which should not be used

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Simply remove the `MYSQL_USER` and it will work fine because the `root` user gets created automatically.

*PS. This seems to be a problem with a newer docker version because this used to work before and not throw an error.*

Comment: but how can create a mysql separate user/password for specific database?

Answer (score 14):

User `root` is reserved and already created with mysql when it's up.

`MYSQL_USER` must be a different name, not `root`.

Comment: Thanks and this does indeed allow me to get _mysql_1 running in Laravel Sail, but there is no sign of my user on the DB. .env contains: DB_USERNAME=lti_laravel_user and docker-compose.yml: MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'. Have already tried this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66077795/laravel-sail-database-user-not-created to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: @theotherdy at first, you can run "docker-compose config" to check all the env variables are loaded to docker-compose correctly.
For the user in mysql, let's try connect to mysql db with that username and password.
And create another question if needed.

Comment: Thanks @user15494648 that does indeed show: MYSQL_USER: lti_laravel_user but there was no user in the DB with that name when using HeidiSQL and connecting root. I just created the user manually in the end. Would be nice to understand what's going wrong though as will be annoying to have to redo this every time I need to rebuild.

Comment: This turned out to be my issue. My .env file was accidentally set to use the root user, which is naughty. When Docker tried to build the image, it attempted to create the database user I requested in the .env file: root. MySql didn't like that and threw errors. Changed the database user to something rational and all worked fine.

Answer (score 11):

I faced the exact same problem and here is how I fixed it.

Go to your docker-compose.yml file and make the following changes:

- "MYSQL_USER: root" to "MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root" then delete the
  previous one.
- "MYSQL_PASSWORD: YourPasseord" to "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
  YourPasseord" then delete the previous one.

  Example:Here is my configuration...

database_server:

```
image: mysql:8.0
       container_name: mysql
       restart: always
       environment:
         MYSQL_DATABASE: DB_epraca
         MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Password
         MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: localhost
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!! This worked for me. And its true.. this is related to some newer versions of docker.

Answer (score 5):

There was recent change how the official mysql docker which caused this issue. For further details you can check [this PR on github](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/pull/749).

For a quick solution you should remove `MYSQL_USER=root` and your `docker-compose.yaml` file should look something like this

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - "3306"
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE # CAP_SYS_NICE
    volumes:
      - ./cache/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./conf-mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Answer (score 3):

Only update your the .env file:

```
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `MYSQL_USER=root` as root user is created by default and when you use
`MYSQL_USER=root` it tries to create a new normal user with name `root`  which cause conflict.
do follow the image in this way:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "paradise"
      MYSQL_USER: "paradise"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "bajbciu2dbwc"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "bajbciu2dbwc"
    ports:
      - "6033:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql  # Map MySQL data directory into the container
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: on-failure:5
    healthcheck:
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

setting `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:"password_of_your_choice"` will set password for root user and setting `MYSQL_USER: "paradise" , MYSQL_PASSWORD: "bajbciu2dbwc"` will create a new user for you.